# String search on dataframe using key/value from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I am trying to match the string present in the below dataframe's 'Disease' column with the key from the dict and if the string is present then change the value in the 'category' column to the value of the dict's key.

df =

| Year | category | Pollutant | Disease | DiseaseCaseCount | Industry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | null | Pb | hypertension | 1025 | b_battery_ltd |
| 2016 | null | PM25 | lung cancer | 180 | t_chemicals |
| 2016 | null | PM25 | lung cancer | 180 | t_powerplant |
| 2016 | null | Cu | lung cancer | 200 | b_miners |
| 2016 | null | Cu | lung cancer | 200 | a_preservative_pvt |
| 2016 | null | PM25 | acute bronchitis | 367 | t_chemicals |
| 2016 | null | PM25 | acute bronchitis | 367 | t_powerplant |

and a dict

```
my_dict = {"cancer": 2, "brain tumor": 8, "acute bronchitis":3}
```

What I have tried till now is

```
for x in my_dict:
    for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
        searchText = row.text
        #print(type(searchText))
        if (searchText.str.lower().str.contains(x).any()):
            row.class = my_dict[x]
        else:
             row.class = None
  
display(df)
```

It throws an error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Final dataframe which I'm looking at is

df =

```
+----+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+
|Year|category|Pollutant|       Disease  |DiseaseCaseCount|          Industry|
+----+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+
|2016|   null |       Pb|    hypertension|            1025|     b_battery_ltd|
|2016|   2    |     PM25|     lung cancer|             180|       t_chemicals|
|2016|   2    |     PM25|     lung cancer|             180|      t_powerplant|
|2016|   2    |       Cu|     lung cancer|             200|          b_miners|
|2016|   2    |       Cu|     lung cancer|             200|a_preservative_pvt|
|2016|   3    |     PM25|acute bronchitis|             367|       t_chemicals|
|2016|   3   |     PM25|acute bronchitis|             367|      t_powerplant|
+----+----+---------+----------------+----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Why not use `df["Disease"].replace(my_dict)`? See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for examples. You can use regex too.

Comment: Your example dataframe doesn't have a 'class' column, by the way. Can you please clarify? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using list comprehension that iterates over the values in the `Disease` column and use `next` and a generator expression to get the dict value if there's a match:

```
df['category'] = [next((v for k,v in my_dict.items() if k in x), float('nan')) for x in df['Disease'].tolist()]
```

Output:

```
   Year  category Pollutant           Disease  DiseaseCaseCount              Industry
0  2016       NaN        Pb      hypertension              1025         b_battery_ltd
1  2016       2.0      PM25       lung cancer               180           t_chemicals
2  2016       2.0      PM25       lung cancer               180          t_powerplant
3  2016       2.0        Cu       lung cancer               200              b_miners
4  2016       2.0        Cu       lung cancer               200    a_preservative_pvt
5  2016       3.0      PM25  acute bronchitis               367           t_chemicals
6  2016       3.0      PM25  acute bronchitis               367          t_powerplant
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and utilize pandas apply(). It's usually much more readable and concise. I am sure there is a more performant way to do it with vectorized function but this way is much more intuitive.

```
def change_class(row, my_dict={"cancer": 2, "brain tumor": 3, "acute bronchitis":8}):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if key == row['Disease']:
            return value
        else: 
            return row['category']

df['category'] = df.apply(lambda x: change_class(x), axis=1)
```